# automatic DIV padding without borders

Tags: css, html

i'm having a rather unique problem with CSS and DIV with/without borders.

Now, when i use the DIV without any borders, there is a kind of automatic padding! when i add a border, the padding disappears.

Even when i use "margin:0;padding:0" it still doesn't clear off the padding.

does anyone have any ideas why it's behaving like this? As a result, i had to use a border with the same color as the page background, but now i have same problem with a set of 3 DIV that should be right next to each other and CANNOT have any borders at all.

HELP!

Comment: Could you post the code here or fiddle it?

Comment: Have you also set "outline:0" ?

Comment: Because `DIV` is by default a block element and its width will be same as the client area of its parent element.